# How to fix "zsh: command not found: ipython"?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ipython, zsh

The following figure shows the installation of ipython

[image]

I use the command `ipython`, but got bad results

[image]

I change the directory many times, but I still cannot open it in the normal way.

The OS is Ubuntu 20.

Comment: When I JUST open a tmux window, the ipython command could be recognized in this tmux window. It's really strange to me.

Comment: try reloading the shell. After installation, ipython executable path is added. Tmux window opens a new shell maybe? See if this works.

Comment: Ensure that either your `path` is set correctly (check with `echo $path`), or invoke `ipython` by specifying the absolute path, or define an alias or shell function for invoking `ipython`.

Comment: Type `hash -r` when you install something, so the cache path is updated.